# Passing Structure to function as argument in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, parameter-passing

I am having this problem and Dont know the reason

I have this structure

```
typedef struct 
{

    Int32   frameID;
    Int32   slotIndx;
    Int32   symNumber;

}   recControlList;


    recControlList  *recControlListPtr;
```

Datatypes are typedefs.

Caller function is :

```
Fun( recControlListPtr);
```

Fun declaration is

```
Fun (recControlList *recControlListPtr);


syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
```

How to I pass structure as pointer into the function? Please help

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the struct declaration and typedef before the declaration of Fun().

If all of this in the same file, then they are just in the wrong order. If the struct is declared in a different file, you need to #include that before the function prototype.

**EDIT** : So on your second question...

Comment: It seems that was the problem. Also I tried to use mandatory struc in function dec as there was no tag ( someone had commented bfor). They both work. I have defined structure in some h file now that is included before function call. Now I get different error:  error: argument of type "recControlList **" is incompatible with parameter of type "recControlList*..pls help

Comment: correction [error: argument of type "recControlList **" is incompatible with parameter of type "recControlList*]

Comment: thanks firoze! but I dont understand this concept, actually I need to declare structure pointer and need to pass to the function. Should I collet it as ** instead of *?

Comment: Actually, I misread your code earlier and thought I saw something I didn't. Sorry about that. So, yes if you want the parameter to be a pointer to a recControlList, then the paramater is recControlList*. (one star)

Answer (score 2):

The declaration is missing a return type, eg:

```
void Fun (recControlList *recControlListPtr);
```

(edit: As pointed out by others, the return type in function declarations is optional in some variants of C, but it's good style and it can give you a better error message due to disambiguation).

Comment: The return type is optional in C. You should get a compiler warning, but not an error.

Comment: Alexandre, C99 allows function declarations without a return type. The type then defaults to "int".

Comment: @davmac C99 removes the implicit int return type. A compiler in C99 mode should produce an error or warning. In C89 it's fine

Comment: @Alexandre you are correct, (your initial claim that "you will get an error" is misleading however).

Answer (score 0):

You just pass it, such as in

```
char* xy = "HelloWorld";
if(!strcmp(xy, "HelloWorld"))
```

You can also do a

```
struct xy ;
functionName(&xy);
```

Did you specify a return value for your function?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer http://fresh2refresh.com/c/c-passing-struct-to-function/ website. Very simple example program is given for Passing structures to function by address. 
I hope this will be useful for you.

Comment: This is a fairly old question which had already been answered. Providing a link without mentioning the relevant sections in your answer is not a very good practice, as the link may become invalid at some point in the future. See [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for some opinions.